# Click event on toolbar button - Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user controls on winforms that contains a toolbar, the problem is whenever the application loses focus then i have to click the toolbar button twice to trigger the click event. I know this is because the first click is for the application to have the focus then then second click will be the actual click event. This only happens to toolbar control but not on other winforms controls.

Answer (score 0):

I got tiered finding the right solution to solve this with ToolStrip control, what I did was I just changed it to Button control set its to Flatstyle then added some mouse hover to mimic the ToolStrip.